# What is the difference between VB6 and VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between VB.NET and previous versions of VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363509/what-are-the-differences-between-vb-net-and-previous-versions-of-vb)

What is the difference between VB6 and VB.NET?  and what are the variants ? ??  I am new in this field hope to get more input on this. Thanks.

Comment: `I am new`.  Then forget that VB6 ever existed.  That was the previous century.

Comment: totally different vb.net OOP while vb6 is not 
vb.net build from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You could say that VB.Net has replaced VB6 in the same way that modern English has replaced medieval English.

I'd suggest starting with wikipedia or google.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_basic
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET

If you're planning to learn one, pick .Net

Comment: Actually I am not concern about the current version or the previous version as there are also VB studio and VB studio express etc right? I just dont know how to differentiate them. v